# (Elasticsearch) Is there a way to add a ± range to the edges of a geo bounding box query?

Tags: elasticsearch, geo

I'd like to be able to do a geo bounding box query in elasticsearch, with some margin for error (mostly incase max and min are given at the same location). Ideally this would give nice rounded corners to the rectangle, with a quater circle on each corner, but simply adding x miles to the top right and subtracting them from bottom left would be sufficient.

I could do this by converting the distance to a differnce in lat long, but this is quite complicated as the mapping changes depending on the actual latitude, so I'd rather not do it that way.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you cannot define a perfectly rounded rectangle, you can approximate it using a [Geo Polygon Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-polygon-query.html) instead of a bounding box, you just need to programmatically calculate some points on the rounded corners; for instance assuming your top-left corner has coordinates x0, y0:

[image]

And so on for the other corners, with as many intermediate points as you want.

However, it seems a little bit of an overkill, you might just want to enlarge your bounding box.

**UPDATE**: another way can be the implementation of a custom function through [Scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), since a GeoPoint's latitude and longitude can be [accessed through scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html#_using_geo_points_in_scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Simply expanding the bounding box will do fine, but working out how many degrees of lat & long to shift the corner based on a given number of miles isn't particularly easy. It's doable, but I was hoping someone knew a more elegant solution, as elasticsearch must be doing this sort of thing behind the scenes anyway (and efficiently) for geo distance queries.

Comment: You could use scripting to implement your own distance function, see my updated answer

Comment: Again, that would work, but my problem isn't that I can't do it, it's that I can't do it neatly, and probably can't do it as efficiently as if there is an easy way to have elasticsearch do this for me.